# Salesforce won't save the month of FISCAL YEAR change

Tags: fiscal-periods

I'm trying to change the fiscal year month for my organization. However, when I click save, it won't save. Is there any reason why this is happening?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You may be affected by this recent Known Issue.  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=salesforce-functionality-impacted-in-%5B%E2%80%A6%5Doss-origin-iframe-javascript-dialogs&Id=a1p4V000002BRMX

Comment: Wow! You were right! I tried it on firefox and it works! Thanks much! I'm not able to mark your comment as an answer. But it really helped!